# Android Sqlite get last insert row id

Tags: android, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get generated id after insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409751/get-generated-id-after-insert)

I want to get the last inserted row id in my android application using this code :

```
String query = "SELECT * from SQLITE_SEQUENCE";
int createdUserId = Integer.parseInt(dbHelper.executeSQLQuery(query).toString());
```

but the problem is that it's throws an exception that cannot convert `dbHelper.executeSQLQuery(query).toString()` to integer. I'm not really good at sqlite ,but i think that this should return the last row id which was inserted...which will definitely will be int (at least I think this way). So if this is not the right way, can someone please guide me how to get the last row id in android application.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What is dbHelper an instance of?

Comment: Why would a `SELECT` statement *insert* anything? If you would actually *insert* something with, say `SQLiteDatabase.insert(...)` you'd get back "the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred".

Comment: @MisterSquonk it's an instance of my DatabaseHelper class.

Comment: @Bombastic: Without seeing the code for your helper class and the `executeSQLQuery(...)` method, it's impossible to say. Philipp is probably correct though - a `SELECT` operation won't return a last inserted row id and you need to be checking that when you actually insert something.

Comment: Here you can see my helper class : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444327/how-to-initialize-sqlite-database-once-from-a-helper-class-in-android

Comment: @Bombastic After looking at your code: Don't make `SQLiteOpenHelper` do things it's not meant for -- its task are creating, upgrading and returning references to the database. You won't get happy with SQLite on Android when you don't call the real query/insert/update/delete methods on a `SQLiteDatabase` instance obtained from your helper.

Comment: @Bombastic: `dbHelper.executeSQLQuery(query)` returns an instance of a `Cursor` therefore you are doing `Integer.parseInt(Cursor.toString())` which is never going to work. Assuming the `id` column of your table is a `long` with `AUTOINCREMENT` then FloatingCoder's method will work although you'll still get a `Cursor` back from the query and you'll have to use `moveFirst()` to be able to access the id's value.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your SQL statrment will return all the row ids, not just the latest. Try something like this...

```
SELECT ROWID from SQL_LITE_SEQUENCE order by ROWID DESC limit 1
```

Also note that I believe selecting from SQL_LITE_SEQUENCE will get the latest ID from ANY table, you can also access the SQL_LITE_SEQUENCE by selecting ROWID on any table, and getting just the IDs for that table. IE

```
SELECT ROWID from MYTABLE order by ROWID DESC limit 1
```

And thanks to MisterSquonk for pointing out the next step in the comments, adding it here for ease of reference later...

The query statement will then return a Cursor object containing the results, so to access the integer value you would do something like this (I'll substitute more common methods for your helper method, just for others sake)

```
String query = "SELECT ROWID from MYTABLE order by ROWID DESC limit 1";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query);
if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
    lastId = c.getLong(0); //The 0 is the column index, we only have 1 column, so the index is 0
}
```

(Note that although the SQL Lite docs call ROWID and Integer, it is a 64 bit integer, so in Java it should be retrieved as a long.)

Comment: Not atomic, unsecure. EDIT: Removed downvote, I thought that was asking another thing.

Comment: There is a theoretical possibility that this may not give the correct answer, because if rows are deleted from the database and then new rows added, after a massive amount of inserts the rowid may reach it's limit at which point sqlite will try to pick random rowid slots to use for a while. Should this happen then obviously the last inserted row does not have the largest numeric value and thus simply sorting the row ids will not suffice.
[Autoincrement In SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Answer (score 12):

Care to use "`select`[`last_insert_rowid()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid)"? :)

Comment: Hey can you explain it a bit please like , how to execute this? i am trying by the Floating Coder's answer, but it is not executing :(

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what your problem is. Maybe you should open new question where you can give more details of what the problem is.

Comment: This is the correct query: SELECT ROWID from MYTABLE order by ROWID DESC limit 1

Comment: I think that will give you the last id from any table, not just the last in your table, correct?

Comment: @weberc2, `last_insert_rowid()` will return the ID which resulted from the *most recent* insert statement executed in the current session, on whatever table that may have been.

Comment: @Marek Bar NOT (if you are working with transactions)...

Comment: @HannoBinder That seems to be what the question is asking: what's the most recent rowid "I want to get the last inserted row id in my android application using this code."