# Android SqlLite update last inserted row

Tags: android

This is what i am using for insert:

```
 public long insert(String content, Date startAt, Date endAt) {
        if (content == null || startAt == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
        contentValues.put(KEY_START_AT, startAt.getTime());
        if (endAt == null) {
            contentValues.putNull(KEY_END_AT);
        } else {
            contentValues.put(KEY_END_AT, endAt.getTime());
        }

        return sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }
```

now i want to create update method which will update last inserted row. How can i get last inserted row?

Comment: Here's another question with a similiar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575166/android-sqlite-get-last-insert-row-id

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575166/android-sqlite-get-last-insert-row-id


Refer this link for getting last inserted row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an id attribute that works as a primary key, you can do a raw database query on SqlLite.

```
Cursor cc = this.mDb.rawQuery("SELECT *" + " FROM " + "<Your DATABASE_NAME> " + 
"ORDER BY id " + "DESC LIMIT 1", null);
return cc;
```

Here,
 1. It returns a cursor.
 2. mDb is a SQLiteDatabase class instance.
 3. ORDER BY id allows the query to sort by id number. As I said, if you have an id as primary key in your table, your latest entry will have the maximum id number.
 4. DESC allows to sort by descending order.
 5. LIMIT 1 allows to return only 1 row.
 6. Always be careful when writing raw queries, white spaces inside the query can be a lot of pain when you do not handle them carefully.

For further queries you can see [this](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/android-developer-tutorial-part-12.html) tutorial. And obviously Divya's answer is also a good one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `cursor` to retrieve rows and say :

```
   cursor.moveToLast();
```

OR

```
  cursor.moveToPosition(cursor.getCount() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you insert a row in to your table the insert query returns the key of the last inserted row. You can now use this key to update this row.

for example

int newInsertedKey = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

update table_name set column_name = 'Change 2' where columnID = newInsertedKey

An efficient method would be to avoid anymore database queries to get the last updated row.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe he should use something like this

```
public long getLastId() {
    Cursor c = mDb.query(currentTableName, new String[] { "MAX(_id)" },
            null, null, null, null, null, null);

            try{
    c.moveToFirst();
    long id = c.getLong(0);
    return id;
            }catch(Exception e){
              return 0;
            }
```

}

where _id is column by which you identify rows