# android sqlite exception cursor or database not closed

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to insert a row in a sqlite database's table, but when I call the insertOrThrow() method (Class Sqlitedatabase) i get this exception:
"Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here"

I don't understand why:

here's the code for the main class:

```
         ........
         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
         values.put("nome", info.getString("nome"));
         values.put("ingredienti", info.getJSONObject("ingredienti").toString());
         values.put("descrizione", info.getString("descrizione"));
         values.put("persone", info.getString("persone"));
         values.put("tempo", info.getString("tempo"));
         values.put("facilita", info.getString("facilita"));
         if(info.getString("url_foto")!="/images/ricettapredefinita.jpg")
            values.put("foto", true);
         else
            values.put("foto", false);
         values.put("categoria", info.getString("categoria"));
         values.put("zona", info.getString("regione"));
         values.put("ethnos", info.getString("etnica"));
         values.put("voto", info.getString("voto"));
        // Open database
        DbAdapter mDbHelper = new DbAdapter(Main.this);
        mDbHelper.open_w();
        long ritorno=mDbHelper.createRecipe(values);
```

These are the main methods for DbAdapter Class:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "CREATE TABLE recipes (" +
    "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
    "nome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL," +
    "ingredienti TEXT NOT NULL," +
    "descrizione TEXT " +
    "persone SMALLINT," +
    "tempo TINYINT(3)," +
    "facilita SMALLINT," +
    "foto BOOL," +
    "voto TINYINT(3)," +
    "categoria VARCHAR(255)," +
    "zona VARCHAR(255)," +
    "ethnos VARCHAR(255));"; 
public long createRecipe(ContentValues info) {
    return mDb.insertOrThrow(DATABASE_TABLE, null, info);
}
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
public DbAdapter open_w() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

Anyone has an idea for what the problem could be?

Comment: close your database in activity's stop or destroy method. mDbHelper.close()

Comment: Create only one instance of DB per application, Reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444327/how-to-initialize-sqlite-database-once-from-a-helper-class-in-android/7446028#7446028

Comment: And how i could do that? how many instances of the DB did I create?

Comment: DbAdapter mDbHelper = new DbAdapter(Main.this);
        mDbHelper.open_w();
        long ritorno=mDbHelper.createRecipe(values); /*And the following line*/ mDBHelper.close();

Comment: I call that in the Main class, but the Exception is thrown in the insertOrThrow method

Answer (score 1):

You should add `mDbHelper.close()` at end.

Comment: At the end of what? Now I tried to open and close the database inside createrecipe() but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

you have to add a mDbHelper.close(); when you are sure that I do not need more a mDbHelper.
I have solved same issue by doing this. I hope is working for u.