# Delete Sqlite Table on Activity start

Tags: android

How i can delete sqlite table when my application start.

my DataBaseHelper have:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion) 
{
   _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CARS");
}
```

But when app start nothing is happening. I want to drop tables if they exist on every start of application.

Thanx

Comment: Why dont you use the onCreate to delete and create new? Or is it just one table not whole db? Also possible you create a new method and call it on app start

Comment: Just 3 tables, i must save 1 table, but i was think maybe if i cannot to delete just table, that i make two .db, one delete, and create new, and one save?

Comment: What library do you use to work with Sqlite?

Comment: @Joseph, to be honest i don't know , i am still noob with android. I have packege android.database.sqlite in android.jar (17) if that help? or can you help me how to check?

Comment: @Nick  please see my answer, and if it helps mark it as your answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnUpgrade is only called if the DB_VERSION has changed, so the database need to be modified or something.

In your case i suggest to create a single Method which is doing the job and call that from the activity method onCreate. Then it it will be called on every start.

Edit:

The Db Helper Class:

```
public static final  String DB_NAME = "MyDbName";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DbHelper(Context context ) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

public void deleteTable() {
    if (db == null || !db.isOpen())
        db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CARS");
}
```

Activity onCreate:

```
dbManager.deleteTable();
```

Comment: Just one question how to define db? (sorry but i still learning) . I have onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db..) but if i define that way, i must define in on activity create to,yes?

Comment: @nick sry, my mistake i'll add it

Comment: This can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444327/how-to-initialize-sqlite-database-once-from-a-helper-class-in-android

Comment: Now i getting error:
08-04 17:50:37.045: E/AndroidRuntime(22940): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 17:50:37.045: E/AndroidRuntime(22940): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.police.car/com.police.car.LoginActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Version must be >= 1, was 0
:(

Comment: @Nick You have to add the Version 1 at least. I added some code as sample

Comment: in your answer.. "db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST CARS");" it's not EXIST.. you are missing an S. it's EXISTS ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I work always on Android with OrmLite, but onUpgrade method is called when version of database change, and when you execute a query to sqlite database. You need to call a method to delete a database.

Answer (score 0):

You can **create a method** that drops the table, and just **call it** on the "onCreate()" of your Activity.

the onUpgrade() method is only called when the DATABASE_VERSION is changed, so there is no guarantee that it will **always** be called on every start.